# Is a power steering flush likely to be necessary at 60k miles?

Tags: power-steering

I was recently sold a power steering flush on a 2010 Civic with 60k miles. Cost: $150. They said the fluid was 'filthy'. I've since read that

1. P/S fluid should last much longer than this,
2. If it was in fact 'filthy', there is likely something more serious wrong with the seals or other components, which I doubt because the steering works fine.

So now I feel scammed. Was I?

Answer (score 5):

Not knowing the exact state of the power steering fluid in the first place, I would be hard pressed to tell you it was a scam. I'm sure they performed the service for which you paid, so at least that portion of it is not a scam.

With that said, you and everyone else should know, this is a typical way that places like Jiffy Lube (or other quick oil change places) do business. It's not that they tell the technicians to go out and scam the customer, but it happens because of how they setup the payment schedule for the technicians. This applies somewhat to service at dealerships as well. What happens is, if a technician (or mechanic at a dealership) spots a problem while performing the work you've asked them to do, they will bring it up to the service manager. The service manager brings it up to you. If you agree to do the extra service, the technician will get paid a higher percentage of this service as it is considered an "add-on" service. Because of this, they are always looking for ways to increase what they get paid, so may "sometimes" suggest services which you really *don't* need. If they can get you to buy it, though, they will get paid the higher amount. Service departments don't really monitor this too much as their gross income will be higher in the process, meaning they show a better bottom line.

If in the future you get this sort of suggestion to have a service done, go and get a second opinion, especially with a technician/mechanic you trust. This is the surest way to get only the services you need, without paying exorbitant amounts of money in the process.

Comment: Agreed. The tough part is finding a mechanic I trust. Been in this town for 2+ years now and still haven't found one.

Comment: The best way to do that is to ask around - don't any of your friends/neighbours/colleagues know someone trustworthy?

Comment: Yes, three of them recommended this place I went to. But perhaps I'm asking the wrong people. As for the condition of the fluid, how could it even have gotten so dirty? Isn't it a closed system? If it really was so dirty, shouldn't they have been looking for some kind of problem with it?

Comment: @hooverlunch ... that's my line of thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding as to how Fluids get dirty in a closed system. There are several ways. The most common are simple wear and tear of parts of the closed loop. Seals wear, bearings wear, fluids may get hot and "Scorch", Rubber hoses disintegrate over time, etc. All of these contaminates enter the fluid circulating thru the system and will make the fluid change colour and degrade the fluid to the point where it needs to be changed to prevent damage to the system it should protect. At 60K miles service was due but the price seems way out of line. I would have paid perhaps $80-$100 tops. The Fluid is not expensive and at max one hour of labour should have covered it. You got "Taken". Next time go to your neighbourhood trustworthy guy. Matter of fact, go now, and ask what he would charge for such service. I think you will be astounded at the cost difference and have him tell you what is involved. Believe me, it is a simple process although it requires a specialised tool.